# JQuery Tabs / Accordion breaks in Chrome but not in FF or IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am a novice with most things programming, so please excuse my ignorance.

I am using a JQuery accordion inside JQuery tabs.  The page works fine on Firefox v12 and IE v9 but breaks in Chrome / Iron v12, specifically clicking on the club name to get the stats for the club causes the tabs to be displayed vertically and the accordion to be a mess.

The page is: http://www.footballfanweb.com/ffwfootballstats/getclubs

If you click on 'Premier League' and then click on a club name the site delivers some stats into the bottom tab area.

I first load using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: 4
    });   

    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });

//  Populate the accordion with football teams for each of the divisions

    $.ajaxCall('myajaxclass.listclubs','div_id=1');
    $.ajaxCall('myajaxclass.listclubs','div_id=2');
    $.ajaxCall('myajaxclass.listclubs','div_id=3');
    $.ajaxCall('myajaxclass.listclubs','div_id=4');

}); /* end document ready */
```

The above ajax calls fills the panels with football team names and writes them as a list of links like this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){        
  $club = $row['club_name'];
  $divstring.='<li title=\"' . $club . '\"><a href=\"#\" >' . $club . '</a></li>'; 
}
```

This produces the list of clubs.

I get the stats using an ajax call and then activate the bottom accordion so that the stats are visible like this:

```
 $("li[title]").live('click', function() {

        var selectedclub = $(this).attr('title');

        $.ajaxCall('myajxclass.getclubinfo', 'theclub=' + selectedclub );       
        $.ajaxCall('myajxclass.statssum','theclub=' + selectedclub );

        $("#accordion").accordion( 'activate' , 4);


    $(function() {
             $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
           });

    });
```

I have searched numerous threads around this problem.  One suggestion was to call the tabs function when I return from the ajax call.  I tried different approaches, e.g.

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select', 0); // zero-based, i.e. 1 = tab 2

$("#accordion").accordion( 'activate' , 4);

$('#tabs').tabs('select', 0);
```

Didn't solve the problem though :(

The html is like this:

```
<div id="tabs">

   <ul>
     <li> flag image 1</li> 
     <li> flag image 2</li>
      ... 
   </ul>

   <div id="tabs-1">

      <div id="accordion">
         // data etc in here.
      </div>

   </div>

   <div id="tabs-2">
        <p> Italy ... Coming soon</p>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

I wondered if Chrome was having problems with invalid html so I validated the page in the w3.org validator and there are two unimportant and unrelated errors:

"required attribute "alt" not specified" 
"there is no attribute "target""

There are no errors in FF firebug.

Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Thanks for any feedback!

Tony

Comment: I can't reproduce using Chrome 19.0.1084.46

Comment: Thanks Ricardo.  It's a real mystery.